# Android Talk back not announcing View Pager2

Tags: android, talkback, accessibility

This is driving me nuts and I can't figure out why android talk back is not announcing the view pager like "page 2 of 4", when I turn on the talk back , view pager start announcing the first textView in the first page,  Can some one help me to get talk back to announce like "page 2 of 4"

```
<androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
            android:id="@+id/view_pager"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/dots_indicator"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <com.tbuonomo.viewpagerdotsindicator.WormDotsIndicator
            android:id="@+id/dots_indicator"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/default_margin"
            app:dotsSize="8dp"
            app:dotsSpacing="4dp"
            app:dotsColor="?colorPrimary"
            app:dotsStrokeColor="@color/color_black_200"
            app:dotsStrokeWidth="4dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/recycler_view" />

  activityBinding.dotsIndicator.setViewPager2(activityBinding.viewPager)
```

when turn on android talk back service, One-finger gesture (Left/right) take between the dots but not announcing the page state like "page 1 of 4", or not announcing the system default

Multi-finger gesture move (Left/right) move to next and previous item but not announcing the page state like "page 1 of 4", or not announcing the system default

How to make this dot indicator as one group and announce the page state